# Могу ли я скриптом создавать scriptableobject со значениями из excel?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть игра с 10000 вопросами и есть SO который позволяет создавать руками вопросы. Но я хотел бы автоматически создавать их подтягивая вопросы из файла и удалять их после использования.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Quiz Question", fileName = "New Question")]
public class QuestionSO : ScriptableObject
{
    [TextArea(2, 6)]
    [SerializeField] string[] answers = new string[4];
    [SerializeField] int correctAnswerIndex;
    [SerializeField] string question = "some text";

    public string GetQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    public string GetAnswer(int index)
    {
        return answers[index];
    }

    public int GetCorrectAnswerIndex()
    {
        return correctAnswerIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel-таблицы можно сохранить в виде простого текста файла в формате CSV - [Comma-Separated Values](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV). Потом этот текстовой файл можно прочитать каким-нибудь csv reader'ом и на основе полученных данных создать требуемый QuestionSO.